# Starting explorer from powershell returns invalid Process ID

Tags: powershell, pid, explorer

I have this script in PowerShell (v2):

```
$n = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath "notepad.exe"
$e = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath "explorer.exe"
$s = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath "explorer.exe" -ArgumentList "/separate"
Write-Host "notepad pid: $($n.Id) explorer pid: $($e.Id) explorer /separate pid: $($s.Id)"
```

My expectation was that I will get the correct process ID in all cases. However, running SysInternals Process Explorer while executing this script, I found that notepad Start-Process returns a valid ID in case of notepad (its the same as in Process Explorer) but in case of explorer I get IDs that I cannot see in Process Explorer, even though I see a new process in the process tree if I add "/separate" as an argument (its ID does not match).

What is wrong here? How can I get the process ID of explorer if I run it with "/separate"?

I read about this issue here in SO: [How to get the process id of Explorer launched from Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084221/how-to-get-the-process-id-of-explorer-launched-from-powershell)
However, that question does not discuss the "/separate" argument and the answer does not provide a solution to get the pid of the new process.

**Update**

I am working on a Windows 7 machine, and I attach a picture how the PIDs mismatch (notepad's PID is OK indicated by green, explorer's PIDs are not OK indicated by red):

[image: PowerShell and Process Explorer]

Comment: IIRC separate was useful in XP and I don't know if it still does what it is supposed to anymore. There is something authoritative out there for sure.

Comment: From what I understand, when you launch Explorer, with or without /separate, the request is handed off to the existing explorer instance. You can read a bit about this behavior here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170328-00/?p=95845

Comment: @Nasir: No, with /separate, I get a new process (I see it in Process Explorer), however I can't get its PID in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

So, you don't mention what OS you are running this on, but this looks like an environmental issue.

Your code block works just fine on:

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Caption
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      16299  98      



($n = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath "notepad.exe")

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
27       3      772       1720       0.02   8888   1 notepad



($e = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath "explorer.exe")

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
28       3      856       1772       0.06  14020   1 explorer



($s = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath "explorer.exe" -ArgumentList "/separate")

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
29       3     1004       1884       0.02   3296   1 explorer



Write-Host "notepad pid: $($n.Id) explorer pid: $($e.Id) explorer /separate pid: $($s.Id)"
notepad pid: 8888 explorer pid: 14020 explorer /separate pid: 3296
```

Using v2 mode on Windows 10

```
 Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17074.1000]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powershell -version 2
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd\
PS C:\> ($n = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath "notepad.exe")

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     --  -- -----------
    230      14     3036      13148 ...21     0.06   1144   2 notepad


PS C:\> ($e = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath "explorer.exe")

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     --  -- -----------
     60      10     2056       5380 ...77     0.02   6184   2 explorer


PS C:\> ($s = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath "explorer.exe" -ArgumentList "/separate")

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     --  -- -----------
     87      10     2052       5920 ...77     0.06   4672   2 explorer


PS C:\> Write-Host "notepad pid: $($n.Id) explorer pid: $($e.Id) explorer /separate pid: $($s.Id)"
notepad pid: 1144 explorer pid: 6184 explorer /separate pid: 4672
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.8860
BuildVersion                   6.1.7600.16385
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think explorer exists on Windows only, and I need it to work on 7 through 10, currently testing on 7.

Comment: Can you confirm that you saw explorer with PIDs 14020, 3296, 6184 and 4672 in Process Explorer or Task Manager? I can get output similar to yours, my problem is that the PIDs of explorer don't match those in Process Explorer or Task Manager.

Comment: Did that already, and yes the IDs are different when using say, 'notepad.exe','explorer.exe'| %{Get-CimInstance Win32_Process | where commandline -match $_} or tasklist /fi "imagename eq  notepad.exe" and tasklist /fi "imagename eq explorer.exe", Win32_Process and TaksList match, and procexp would show the same thing as TaskList.. Notpad is the same across all there explorer is the one that shows difference the call set.